# Getting each wallet address balance

Tags: ethereum

I’m currently having a hard time figuring how to get to check users wallet addresses and get the balances ie if a user wants to send out 3Eth and they have like 10 addresses with different amounts inside them, how do I subtract the amount from each address to get the 3Eth the user wants to send out?

Comment: I'm unclear on whether you're asking about Ethereum or Bitcoin. You've used both tags, but the text of your question seems to just be about Bitcoin.

Comment: That was an oversight, I’m asking about ethereum

Comment: Then please edit your post.

Comment: Edited the post already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ethereum (unlike Bitcoin), each transaction can only have one `from` address. So to transfer ether from *n* addresses, you'll need *n* transactions.

Comment: Thank you so much, please can you quickly give me a workaround on how to achieve this too in bitcoin??

Comment: Create a new question about Bitcoin if you can't find the answer elsewhere.